# Escaping quotes and tags to pass data in JS function

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have a table in which I am saving blog body data, the data is gone through TINYMCE editor and it saves tags and styling. When I am fetching the data for editing purpose and passing it through the function to open a modal it shows the tags and everything and outputting the data in button.
Here is the code:

```
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" 
        onclick="getData('<?php echo $blog->title?>','<?php echo 
        $blog->body?>',
        <?php echo $blog->id?>')">Update</a> 
    </td>
```

This is the getData function

```
 function getData(title,body,id) {
     debugger;
     document.getElementById('title1').value = title;
     tinymce.get('body').setContent(body);
     document.getElementById('blog_id').value = id;

     $('#myModalUpdate').modal('show');
 };
```

This is how it outputs on the page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7xmX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to think about each layer one at a time.

First you have some data…

```
$blog->title
```

… and you want to put it into JavaScript. So you have to escape it to make it safe for JavaScript. `json_encode` will do this because JSON is a subset of JS. Since you are putting a string in, you get a JSON string literal out, so you mustn't add the quotes manually.

```
$js_safe_title = json_encode($blog->title);
$js_safe_body = json_encode($blog->body);
$js = "getData($js_safe_title, $js_safe_body);"
```

… and then you want to put that JS into an HTML attribute, so you have to escape it to make it safe for HTML:

```
$html_safe_js = htmlspecialchars($js);
```

Then you can put it in the HTML:

```
 onclick="<?=$html_safe_js?>"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, You are a saviour. This helped.